# D3.js: first part of the ordinal axis added 2 times

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I make a scale:

```
d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(monthds)
  .rangeRoundBands([0, w]);
```

then make sAxis and adding it to the svg:

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
   .call(xAxis);
```

But for some reason the first 2 months are drawn two times. Heres a link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uyitis/22/edit

Comment: looks fine when i view it. maybe add a screen shot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Seems like jsbin refresh problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen commented it looks fine.  I've bumped the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ukuDOxa/1/) to tidy the axis a bit.  The x-axis was hanging over to the side a bit so I moved to the right by adding in the padding, as in:

```
//Create X axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate("+ padding + "," + (h - padding) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);
```

The date scale range also had to be updated with the padding to stop Oct being lost, as in:

```
var xDateScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                               .domain(monthds)
                               .rangeRoundBands([0, w-padding]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like jsbin drawn it two times, as when I reloaded my example it looked good for me as well.